# Can StringTokenizer countTokens ever be zero?

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I just found a piece of Java code inside a method:

```
if (param.contains("|")) {
  StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(param.toLowerCase().replace(" ", ""), "|");
  if (st.countTokens() > 0) {
    ...
  }
} else {
  return myString.contains(param);
}
```

Can `countTokens` in the above case ever be less than 1?

Comment: Why don't you try it? You can easily build an example..

Answer (score 5):

It can, if the string you're trying to tokenize is empty, otherwise it'll always at least be 1

Example 1:

```
String myStr = "abcdefg";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(myStr, ";");
int tokens = st.countTokens();
System.out.println("Number of tokens: " + tokens);

> "Number of tokens: 1"
```

Example 2:

```
String myStr = "";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(myStr, ";");
int tokens = st.countTokens();
System.out.println("Number of tokens: " + tokens);

> "Number of tokens: 0"
```

Example 3:

```
String myStr = "abc;defg";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(myStr, ";");
int tokens = st.countTokens();
System.out.println("Number of tokens: " + tokens);

> "Number of tokens: 2"
```

Answer (score 3):

Below return `0`:

- `new StringTokenizer("", "|").countTokens()`
- `new StringTokenizer("|", "|").countTokens()`
- `new StringTokenizer("||||", "|").countTokens()`

so `countTokens()` returns `0` when:

- the `String` is empty
- the `String` contains only the delimeter

Answer (score 1):

Look at this

```
    String param="";
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(param.toLowerCase().replace(" ", ""), "|");
    System.out.println(st.countTokens());
```

answer is 0(zero)

Comment: So if param is never empty AND myString does contain the delimiter THEN it will never be lower than 1, is that correct?

Comment: The answer is 0 (zero) not o ;)

Comment: @DrH: if param is never empty then it will never be lower than 1.

Comment: Thank you @Burkhard. Then I suppose in that case `nextToken` won't result either in an empty substring meaning a `countTokens` of a tokenizer inside another tokenizer will also return with at least 1.

Comment: @Ruchira: you can see your original post by clicking on the link under "edited x mins ago". You wrote o instead of 0.

Comment: I am guessing you can see it too. It was 0 not o.

Comment: @Ruchira: Nope, I cannot. It clearly was an o (http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/b9288157-ef74-41a4-a65f-3323caa88acd/view-source)